# Pig min command and order by

Tags: apache-pig

I have data in the form of shell, $917.14,$654.23,2013

I have to find out the minimum value in column $1 and $2

I tried to do a order by these columns by asc order

But the answer is not coming out correct. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer  [MIN](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#min)

```
A = LOAD 'test1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (f1:chararray,f2:float,f3:float,f4:int,f5:int,f6:int);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE MIN(A.f2),MIN(A.f3);
DUMP C;
```

[image: Output]

**EDIT1:** The data you are loading has '$' in it.You will either have to clean it up and load it to a float field to apply MIN function or load it into a chararray and replace the '$' and then cast it to float and apply the MIN function.

**EDIT2:** Here is the solution without removing the $ in the original data but handling it in the PigScript.

**Input**:

```
shell,$820.48,$11992.70,996,891,1629
shell,$817.12,$2105.57,1087,845,1630
Bharat,$974.48,$5479.10,965,827,1634
Bharat,$943.70,$9162.57,939,895,1635
```

**PigScript**

```
A = LOAD 'test5.txt' USING TextLoader() as (line:chararray);
A1 = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'([^a-zA-Z0-9.,\\s]+)','');
B = FOREACH A1 GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0,','));
B1 = FOREACH B GENERATE $0,(float)$1,(float)$2,(int)$3,(int)$4,(int)$5;
C = GROUP B1 ALL;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE CONCAT('$',(chararray)MIN(B1.$1)),CONCAT('$',(chararray)MIN(B1.$2));
DUMP D;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: @Jigyasa Post sample data,your script and expected output.Are you trying to determine which column is lesser between the 2 column values or trying to get the minimum value in 2 columns?

Comment: Sample Data :   Shell,$123.12,$678.13,2013

Comment: Sample data:
shell,$820.48,$11992.70,996,891,1629
shell,$817.12,$2105.57,1087,845,1630
Bharat,$974.48,$5479.10,965,827,1634
Bharat,$943.70,$9162.57,939,895,1635

Requirement is to find out the minimum of $1

A = load 'text.csv' using pigstorage (',');
B = ORDER A BY $1 ASC;
C= LIMIT B 1;
D= FOREACH C GENERATE $0,$1;

And

A = load 'text.csv' using pigstorage (',');
B = GROUP A BY $0;
D= FOREACH C GENERATE A.$0,MIN(A.$1);

But non of them is giving correct ans.

Comment: Exected output should be $817.12 for column $1 and 2105.57 for $2 column

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the data has $ sign in them.

Comment: I have removed the $ sign from the data but still the output is not correct.

Comment: @Jigyasa How is not correct? See the script that I have posted and the output.Have you specified the schema i.e.  as (f1:chararray,f2:float,f3:float,f4:int,f5:int,f6:int); in the load statement? if not data will be loaded into chararray and min cannot be applied to chararray fields

Comment: Can not load it as float as it has $ sign in it an i can't change the data while loading

Comment: You just said that you removed the $ sign

Comment: Did it replace the $? and then did you cast that field to float?

Comment: Cast i dont know about this

Comment: When you replace it returns a chararray, you will have to cast it to float and then apply MIN

Comment: @Jigyasa. I've edited the answer to handle $ sign.If it helps please mark it as answer.